# Upload não funciona $_FILES undefined index error

Tags: php

Ao fazer o upload de um arquivo estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in Z:\web\upload.php on line 3

upload.php:

```
<?php
$location = 'uploads/';
$arquivo = $_FILES['file'];

if ($arquivo) {
    $name = $arquivo['name'];
    $tmp_name = $arquivo['tmp_name'];

    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload:', $error;
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
        echo 'Uploaded';    
    }
}
```

Formulário:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Senhor Downvoter por favor leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer e http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange e se tiver algum outro motivo pro downvote justifique.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Para fazer uploads de arquivos é necessário setar o `enctype` para `multipart/form-data` na tag `<form>`

Exemplo:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
```

Além disto é recomendável usar [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) para fazer os tratamentos de erros:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $arquivo = $_FILES['file'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

O código deve ficar assim:

upload.php

```
<?php
$location = 'uploads/';

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload:', $error;
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
        echo 'Uploaded';    
    }
} else {
    echo 'Selecione um arquivo para fazer upload';
}
```

Formulário:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### O que é `enctype`?

O atributo `enctype` define como os dados do formulário serão codificados ao enviar os dados para o servidor, existem 3 tipos de valores para este atributo:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` este é o valor padrão. Nele todos caracteres são codificados antes de serem enviados, por exemplo espaços são trocados por `+` e caracteres especiais são convertidos em valores ASCII HEX.
- `multipart/form-data` Ele não codificado os dados, você deve usar este valor quando for fazer uploads.
- `text/plain` espaços são convertidos em sinais de `+` mas outros caracteres não serão codificados.

Comment: Excelente essa resposta pois coloca em evidência o tratamento de imagens antes do processamento do formulário como um todo.