# Como obter todas as propriedades da imagem no upload?

Tags: php, upload, imagem

Estou aqui navegando no Google mas não achei de uma forma clara como obter todas as propriedades da imagem no momento do upload no script.

Estou usando pra pegar a imagem:

```
$imagem = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
```

***Pergunta:*** Como obter todas as propriedades da imagem no momento do upload com o `$_FILES`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se fizer assim:

```
print_r($_FILES['arquivo']);
```

Ele vai lhe dar todas propriedades:

```
Array (
    [name] => arquivo.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5Wx0aJ
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 15726
)
```

- `name` retorna o nome do arquivo
- `type` retornar o mimetype enviado pelo multipartbody (este não 
  é um metodo confiavel de verificar o tipo do arquivo, leia abaixa que tera uma alterantiva)
- `tmp_name` é o local aonde foi feito o upload do arquivo, ou seja a função `move_upload_file` apenas move o arquivo desta pasta.
- `erro` retornar algum numero diferente de zero se houver alguma falha no upload, caso contrário será `0` que significa que ocorreu tudo bem.
- `size` é o tamanho do arquivo.

Note que pro upload funcionar é necessário o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, assim:

```
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Como dito nesta pergunta: [Upload não funciona $_FILES undefined index error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50988/3635)

### Tratando erros de upload

Note que se o upload retornar algum erro ele será um numero através da chave `[error]`, segue a lista de constantes que você usará pra saber qual erro ocorreu:

- `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`

  Valor: 0; não houve erro, o upload foi bem sucedido.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`

  Valor 1; O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva `upload_max_filesize` do `php.ini`.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`

  Valor: 2; O arquivo excede o limite definido em `MAX_FILE_SIZE` no formulário HTML.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`

  Valor: 3; O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`

  Valor: 4; Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR`

  Valor: 6; Pasta temporária ausente. Introduzido no PHP5.0.3.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE`

  Valor: 7; Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco. Introduzido no PHP 5.1.0.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION`

  Valor: 8; Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo. O PHP não fornece uma maneira de determinar qual extensão causou a interrupção. Examinar a lista das extensões carregadas com o `phpinfo()` pode ajudar. Introduzido no PHP 5.2.0.

Exemplo de uso:

```
switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
        //Upload funcionou
    break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        throw new RuntimeException('Arquivo não foi enviado');
    break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        throw new RuntimeException('Tamanho excedido.');
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException('Erro desconhecido');
}
```

### Verificando o mimetype

Note que usar a chave `[type]` não é um método eficaz de verificar o tipo do arquivo pois ele não verifica os dados reais do arquivo upado.

Verificar a extensão também não um método eficaz, pois você pode colocar a extensão que quiser no arquivo, o melhor é fazer a verificação com a função `finfo`, como eu já citei nesta resposta:

- [Comparar extensão de arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635)

Comment: Muito bom esta resposta e a outra complementa muito bem esta :)

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Obrigado! Adicionei mais alguns detalhes.