# AJAX javascript, PHP post não funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Bom dia, estou criei um código javaScript para enviar dados usando AJAX para uma página PHP,meu problema é que o POST está indo vazio para página que estou chamando. Isso só acontece quando chamo a função JavaScript(AJAX) que faz o request, quando chamo a página PHP direto pelo action o POST funciona normalmente. O que pode ser?

```
 function AjaxExecute(arquivo){
        var ajax;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ 

            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        } else {

            try{
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }   
        }

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){

                return this.responseText;
            }
        }

        ajax.open("post",arquivo);
        ajax.send(null);

}
```

Comment: Coloca os `headers` e a `url`. E o que seria arquivo ?

Comment: o **arquivo** seria minha **url**, fiz assim porque pretendo usar essa mesma função para mais casos. Tentei usar o **header**, mas não havia funcionado então removi.

Answer (score 2):

Está a faltar a `url`, e definir o `header`:

```
...
var url = "receberFicheiro.php";
ajax.open("post", url, "true");
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
      # ???
      return this.responseText;
   }
}
ajax.send(ficheiro);
```

E atenção ao `return`.

Comment: a url seria o minha variavel **arquivo**, em outra tentativa tentei colocar o **setRequestHeader**, porém não rolou também, o return segundo o comentário abaixo posso usar um callback, porém como recupero o valor retornado em outro script js?

Answer (score 1):

1. Troque o return por um `callback` (leia isto [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635))
2. E por fim ajuste o if para detectar erros HTTP ou de conexão:
3. Depois ajuste o *header* para usar POST (leia isto [AJAX Javascript Puro Assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117483/3635))

   ```
   function AjaxExecute(arquivo, variaveis, success, fail){
       var ajax;

       variaveis = !variaveis ? null : variaveis;

       if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ 

           ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

       } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

           try{
               ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
           }catch(e){
               ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
       } else {
           //Simula um erro acaso Ajax não esteja disponivel (quase improvavel)
           setTimeout(error, 1, 0);
           return;
       }

       ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

           if(ajax.readyState == 4){
               if (ajax.status == 200) {
                   //Callback se retornar status HTTP 200
                   success(this.responseText);
               } else {
                   //Calllback se retornar qualquer outro status até 0 (sem conexão)
                   fail(ajax.status);
               }
           }
       }

       ajax.open("post", arquivo);

       //Ajusta a requisição para trabalhar o POST
       ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

       //Envia os dados via POST
       ajax.send(variaveis);
   }

   function sucesso(resposta) {
       alert(resposta);
   }

   function erro(codigo) {
       alert("Erro na requisição:" + codigo);
   }

   AjaxExecute("pagina.php", "foo=1&bar=2", sucesso, erro);
   ```

Comment: `fail` -> `erro`

Comment: @Edilson fail é dentro do escopo de `AjaxExecute` e `erro` é uma função fora, inclusive testei e funcionou normalmente (os nomes dentro do escopo estão em inglês, fora seriam funções criado por ele).

Comment: Estou com algumas dúvidas, o código que você enviou funcionou, porém como faço para pegar esse retorno em outro script JS? e a página ainda está atualizando, como faço para ela não atualizar?

Comment: Não entendi @RayanPereiradeLima

Comment: ja passei assim  **ajax.open("post", arquivo, true);** e assim **ajax.open("post", arquivo, false);**

Comment: Continuo não entendendo a sua duvida: *"porém como faço para pegar esse retorno em outro script JS?"* @RayanPereiradeLima

Comment: Na verdade minha primeira preocupação é que a página está atualizando ainda. Pesquisei aqui, mas não achei nada que me ajude. Sobre a outra dúvida seria o seguinte, se eu colocasse isso function sucesso(resposta) {
   return resposta; 
}
daria certo? porque tentei e não consigo pegar esse retorno em outro script onde trato isso. Como eu disse eu gostaria de usar essa função como genérica.

Comment: Você quer dizer que a página esta mudando a url na barra de endereços? @RayanPereiradeLima

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57174/discussion-between-rayan-pereira-de-lima-and-guilherme-nascimento).