# Notice: Undefined index em variavel $_FILES (upload PHP)

Tags: php, html

Eu criei esse código para adicionar produtos a minha base de dados, só que ocorre um erro na imagem, diz que eu não a defini.

o código é esse:

```
<?php   
ob_start();
session_start();
require 'ligarDb.php';


$error = false;
$nameError ="";
$imagem ="";


 if(isset($_POST['btn-add'])){ 


        $nameP = trim($_POST['nameP']);// o trim elimina espaços na string 
        $nameP = strip_tags($nameP);// Retira as tags HTML e PHP de uma string
        $nameP = htmlspecialchars($nameP);// Converte caracteres especiais para a realidade HTML

        $preco = trim($_POST['preco']);
        $preco = strip_tags($preco);
        $preco = htmlspecialchars($preco);

        $size = trim($_POST['size']); 
        $size = strip_tags($size);
        $size = htmlspecialchars($size); 

        $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
        $estado = strip_tags ($estado);
        $estado = htmlspecialchars($estado);

        $cor = trim($_POST['cor']);
        $cor = strip_tags($cor);
        $cor = htmlspecialchars($cor);

        $descricao = trim($_POST['descricao']);
        $descricao = strip_tags($descricao);
        $descricao = htmlspecialchars($descricao);

        $imagem  = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
        $img_dir = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['foto']['size'];


 //validação do Nome Produto

    if(empty($nameP)){
                 $error = true;
                 $nameError = "Preencha o nome.";
    }else if (strlen($nameP) < 3) {
                 $error = true;
                 $nameError = "Nome tem de ter mais caracteres.";
    } else if (empty($imagem)) {
                $error = true;
                $imgError = "Por favor selecione uma imagem.";
    } else {

        $upload_dir = '../upload/'; //diretório onde será guardada a imagem.
        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imagem, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    //validação de extensao 

        $valid_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png');
    // 
        $user_pic = rand(1000,1000000)." . ".$imgExt;

    // valida os formatos das imagens
        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_ext)){
            //verifica se o tamanho é de 5MB
            if($imgSize < 5000000 ){
                move_uploaded_file($img_dir,$upload_dir.$user_pic);
            } else {
                $imgError = "Desculpa, a sua imagem é muito grande.";
            }
        }  else {
            $imgError = "Desculpe, apenas extesões JPG, JPEG, PNG.";
        }

    }

 if(!$error){  

$addnew = mysqli_query($ligacao, "INSERT INTO products (nomeP,preco,estado,tamanho,cor,descricao, imagem) VALUES ('$nameP','$preco','$estado','$size','$cor','$descricao', '$user_pic')");

    if($addnew) {
          $errTyp = "successo";
          $errMSG = "Registrado com sucesso.";
          header('refresh: 10; form_addnew.php');
              unset($nameP);
              unset($preco);
              unset($size);
              unset($estado);
              unset($cor);
              unset($descricao);
              unset($user_pic);
   } else {
    $errTyp = "Erro";
    $errMSG = "Tem algo errado, tente mais tarde..."; 
   } 

  }
}

?>

 <!--começa o formulario-->
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>

        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-2-3">
                <form id="my-login-form" method="post" action="" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2 class="">Adicionar novo / <a href="mySnoop.php">Voltar</a></h2>   
                    </div>



   <!--abriu o php $errMSG-->   <?php
              if (isset($errMSG)){ 
            ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="alert alert-<?php echo ($errTyp=="successo ") ? "success0 " : $errTyp; ?>"> <span class="glyphicon"></span>
                                <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php  } ?> <!--fechou o php $errMSG-->


                            <!--tabelas d formulario-->
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Nome:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nameP" required placeholder="" value="" /></div> <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span> 
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Categoria:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" required placeholder="" value="" /></div> <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span> 
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-row required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Preço:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="preco"   placeholder="" value="" required /> </div>
                                <span class="text-danger">
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Tamanho:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="size"   placeholder="" value="" required /> </div>
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Estado:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="estado"  placeholder="" value="" required /></div>
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span> 
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-row required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Cor:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cor"  placeholder=" " value="" required /></div>
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span> 
                            </div>

                              <div class="form-row required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Descrição:</label>
                                    <textarea type="text" name="descricao"  placeholder="" value="" required/></textarea></div>
                                    <span class="text-danger"></span> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <div class="input_something">
                                    <label for="">Imagem:</label>
                                    <input  name="foto" type="file" placeholder="" value=""/></div> <span class="text-danger"> </span> 
                            </div><br>

                                 <input name="btn-add" type="submit" value="Registrar" />
                            <!-- botao entrar-->
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-1-4"><img src="imgs/publicidade.png"></div>
        </div>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

O erro apresentado é este:

> Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\snoop\form_addnew.php
>   on line 39 Notice: Undefined index: foto in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\snoop\form_addnew.php on line 40 Notice: Undefined
>   index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\snoop\form_addnew.php on line 41

Comment: Jolene, poderia inserir o erro que ocorreu também?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\snoop\form_addnew.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\snoop\form_addnew.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\snoop\form_addnew.php on line 41

Comment: é referente a essa parte do codigo
        $imagem  = $_FILES['foto']['name']; //39
        $img_dir = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']; // 40
        $imgSize = $_FILES['foto']['size'];   // 41

Comment: Jolene, o ideal é colocar o erro na pergunta, editando ela. Mas já coloquei o erro lá, entao pode deixar.

Comment: william resolvi dessa forma... $imagem = isset($_FILE['foto']['name']), so que agora ele nao faz registro na base de dados :(

Comment: Jolene, na verdade você resolveu o erro. O erro acontece porque esse dado referente ao upload da foto por algum motivo nao está sendo salvo e ele tenta acessar um dado que não existe. agora ele somente não salva   o dado. mas essa dado continua nao aparecendo. Vou tentar verificar o motivo aqui e respondo.

Comment: Obrigado william

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O único erro que encontrei no seu código foi no trecho abaixo, onde o enctype=**”multipart/form-data”** não está com `"` (aspas) corretamente.

É necessária a inserção deste atributo no `form` para que o upload de arquivos funcione. O que estava acontecendo é que por causa das aspas erradas ele não estava sendo reconhecido, conforme trecho abaixo no seu código.

```
<form id="my-login-form" method="post" action="" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
```

Favor corrigir o trecho colocando as aspas **conforme o trecho abaixo** e verifique se funcionou:

```
<form id="my-login-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

<sub>Referência:
 [PHP 5 File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)</sub>

Comment: obrgado william, era mesmo isso, acabei de trocar as virgulas altas por aspas.

Comment: Jolene, sinta se a vontade para marcar a minha resposta como a certa. Que bom que te ajudou! =D

Comment: >>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50988/3635 :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no caso dela o erro é diferente.

Comment: Mas são bem parecidas mesmo

Comment: É verdade, eu não havia notado, estranho essas aspas, até aonde sei geralmente só se digitar algo pelo msword ou similar elas aparecerem, ela deve ter copiado o código de algum lugar sem prestar atenção.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acredito que foi isso mesmo.