# Erro em upload de imagem com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload

Ao enviar  o formulário cadastra nome, e-mail e senha, mas a imagem não cadastra e não consigo encontrar o erro.

Algumas tentativas sem sucesso:

- Ao colocar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` o arquivo posta para o MySQL o `temp`, mas não posta a imagem para a pasta.

Código:

```
<?php
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])){
    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
    $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

    $picture    = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $img_name = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $dir      = "/var/www/uploads/";
    $path     = $dir.$img_name;
    move_uploaded_file( $picture, $path );  

    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, picture, date) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$picture' ,'$date')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($result){
        echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
}else{
?>
```

Meu formulário

```
 <form name="registration" action="" method="post">
 Upload Imagen : <input type="file" name="foto" />
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
  </form>
```

Minha tabela no banco:

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `ative` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `date` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` no formulário? É necessário ter.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Upload não funciona $\_FILES undefined index error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50988/upload-n%c3%a3o-funciona-files-undefined-index-error)

Comment: ja tentei mas ele posta como /tmp/phpTWuYuc  temporario e nao envia a imagem para a pasta upload

Comment: Então você já identificou um comportamento estranho no código... Por favor, edite sua pergunta e descreva **EXATAMENTE** o que você tentou fazer e o que está acontecendo no código.

Comment: Provavelmente sua pasta `/var/www/uploads/` não tem permissão de escrita e execução. Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Primeiro: não faz sentido você armazenar `$picture` no MySQL visto que ele é o caminho temporário do arquivo. Melhor seria salvar `$path`. Segundo: o diretório `uploads` existe? Terceiro: verifique o retorno da função `move_uploaded_file` e ative as mensagens de erro. [Documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php).